# how to make WPF button has dropdown list arrow without using background?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I Have a button that will show popup looks like dropdownlist but can be dragged 
so I need the dropdownlist's arrow /   to inform the user that a popup will appear after clicking on this button .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the button you can use:

```
            <Button >
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                            <Path VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,2,0,0" Fill="Black" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>

            </Button>
```

Comment: Can we change Property "Fill" Value dynamically depending if button enabled or disabled using trigger ? so if the control disabled I want to fill it with gray , that would be perfect. thanks so much btw

Comment: Sure.. you can define the style for the Path above and put DataTrigger to capture button's IsEnabled change and set Fill in setter